# Make a combination with ascending numbers in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my list:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If I do this:

```
from itertools import permutations
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
l = []

lperm = permutations(lst,3)
for i in lperm:
    l.append(i)

print(l)
```

It returns this:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 2), ...]
```

But this is what I want:

```
[(1, 2, 3),(2, 3, 4),(3, 4, 5)]
```

Anyone has an answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = 3
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print([lst[x:x+l] for x in range(len(lst)-l+1)])
```

or if you need those tuples:

```
print([tuple(lst[x:x+l]) for x in range(len(lst)-l+1)])
```

If you don't want to hold all the values in the memory:

```
l = 3
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


def slider(iterable, l):
    for x in range(len(iterable)-l+1):
        yield tuple(lst[x:x+l])


for i in slider(lst, l):
    print(i)
```